# AWS CDN for single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cdn

As per the title, is it possible to apply Amazon CloudFront to a single EC2 instance without creating 2 instances in different available zones? (it'd be too expensive to pay for two instances)

Comment: What do you mean by "apply a CDN"? The only AWS CDN I can think of is [Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html), which just needs a source URL, and doesn't care how that's hosted.

Comment: Yes my bad, I have modified the description. I need to set up an Amazon CloudFront to a single ec2 instance (not to a S3 bucket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a CloudFront distribution in front of a single EC2 instance. Your EC2 instance needs a public IP address. When you create the CloudFront distribution, make sure to use the public IPv4 DNS name of your instance as origin, because IP addresses are not allowed as origin name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Some useful videos I've found:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzXZhU656V0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVbwVet8aI4